# Getting link from HTML (Selenium and Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML:

[image]

I want to get that selected image URL.

Till the moment, i've just tried:

```
quest = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="table--database"]/div/div[2]/div/div')
print(quest.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

but when I execute it I get:
div class="table__empty instead of div class = table__body

What's going on?

Comment: Can you share the original url or complete  html source code? '

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @PedroLobito it's really long. Is there any way to paste it without using so much space?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this Xpath

```
quest = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="table--database"]//div[@class="table__body"]//img')
# or
# quest = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="table--database"]//img')
# quest = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="table__body"]//img')
print(quest.get_attribute('src')) # URL only
print(quest.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately dind't work, it's like that part of the code is not visible or something like that

Comment: maybe you need to add `WebDriverWait`